# Update JSON data source on button click tableview swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Getting confuse in updating data source local JSON file. I have the list showed in tableview with Add button. I need to perform an action on button event to add specific row on top of section. I am using delegates. Data list based on section wise.

> Link: 
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cufp7hHNEVe4zZ7TiSCjFvFLm7EAWuXo/view?usp=sharing

```
extension DelegateViewController: DictionaryTableDelegate{
    func didAddnewRow(_ tag: Int) {
        print("Add Button with a tag: \(tag)")
        AppList?.selectedValue?.append("Welcome")


        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: AppData?.sectionList?.count ?? 0 - 1, section: 0)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

> Error:
>   Attempt to insert row 3 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update

Comment: Unrelated with your problem; don't use begin/end updates, that's for batch operations, you use a single operation. Don't reload table view after insert, it does that for you.

Comment: @Desdenova In both cases it's not working. I have tried a lot. `Error : attempt to insert row 3 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update`

Comment: Thats because you aren't updating your data source. You also need to insert that data in to your source.

Comment: @Desdenova Yes exactly, how can I update data source? Can you please guide me I tried but stuck.

Comment: What is your data source, exactly what is the issue when it comes to updating it?

Comment: Just remove the whole `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` if you not sure what you are doing and use `reloadData` only, it will crash if there's unbalance between ui rows and record in `sectionList `

Comment: Ok, I saw your project. After you decode your local json, you create a `ListData` object and use it as your data source. Now when you tap 'add' button, you need to get `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row`. Section will be your index for `SectionList` position and Row will be your index for `Item` position. You need to create a new `Item` object and append it in your data source.

Comment: After reading your question again, we have no idea what you are trying to insert and where do you want your new data.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `AppData` is the data source, `ListData` is the model and I am not able to update data source properly.

Comment: @Desdenova The populated list is in the below sections `A B or C` I need to select them actually.  once its selected it move to top section. `AppData` data source & `ListData` is the model. In my project I have placed the image as well that what results I need to achieve.

Comment: Well I see no such code, add any relevant code to your question if you expect want us to help you. Unrelated but this looks wrong `AppData?.sectionList?.count ?? 0 - 1`, if there is no `sectionList` it will return -1

Comment: @JoakimDanielson .Project Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cufp7hHNEVe4zZ7TiSCjFvFLm7EAWuXo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am not going to use some external resource, you post your code here. Links or their content may go away making the question impossible to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have see your projects, there are some changes required as follow to add selected item from bottom sections to add in top sections.

First of all update your `DictionaryTableDelegate` method as follow:

```
protocol DictionaryTableDelegate {
    func didAddnewRow(_ sender: UIButton)
}
```

then change delegate call as follow.

```
@IBAction func addClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didAddnewRow(sender)
}
```

Change `items` from `let` to `var`

```
struct SectionList : Codable {
    let title : String?
    var items : [Item]?
}
```

same here, change `sectionList` from `let` to `var`

```
struct ListData : Codable {
    var sectionList : [SectionList]?    
}
```

Update code of `didAddnewRow` as follow will fix your issue:

```
extension DelegateViewController: DictionaryTableDelegate{

    func didAddnewRow(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? DictionaryTableViewCell,
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        {
            if let selectedItem = AppData?.sectionList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row] {

                let insertIndexPath = IndexPath(item: AppData?.sectionList?[0].items?.count ?? 0, section: 0)

                AppData?.sectionList?[0].items?.append(selectedItem)

                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to remove selected row from bottom section then update following code

```
func didAddnewRow(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? DictionaryTableViewCell,
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell),
        indexPath.section != 0
    {
        if let selectedItem = AppData?.sectionList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row] {

            let insertIndexPath = IndexPath(item: AppData?.sectionList?[0].items?.count ?? 0, section: 0)

            AppData?.sectionList?[0].items?.append(selectedItem)
            AppData?.sectionList?[indexPath.section].items?.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you, I have made the changes accordingly but getting `reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update` Let me share the updated code link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1maRuKe8KEH9Fw2PgVSWsOtX3iETshwTS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Done it little tweak it and done. Thank you so much for your support.